# How to include a debugger in phpmyadmin in my cPanel

Tags: php

I have to write a few php scripts and for that I don't want to install a wamp/lamp server.

I will be writing these scripts directly on the cPanel on my server side.

So if I run the script and there is any error it doesn't show me the line number or anything instead just gives a message that the url is not available which makes it difficult to debug.

So how can I debug my code if I am writing directly on the server side. Is there any software or anything that I can install?

My Code : Here I have removed the semi colon in the $query line to make the error, otherwise the code is fine.

```
<?php

/* Make connection database*/
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","*****", "****", "****");

/*Function to check connection*/
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connection failed : %s \n",mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$query = "SELECT * FROM music ORDER BY id DESC"

if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)){
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        if($i == 0){
            echo "$row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3]";
        } 
        else{
            echo "*$row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3]";
        } 
        $i++;

    } 
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: How can you write scripts in Cpanel, It is a graphical presentation of tools right ?

Comment: @zan It is a GUI. I make a folder inside the file manager and in there I have my php scripts which run.

Comment: is your display_error on ?

Comment: @zan No, I am new to php. Will that display the errors in the browser or somewhere else?

Comment: After enabling you can see errors in the browser itself. Check this our for enabling https://support.hawkhost.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/128/11/how-can-i-enable-php-error-reporting

Comment: @zan That didn't help in debugging. It just shows internal server error and the error code. What I need is the line number and the error message like the regular debugger so that can debug the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Write this two line at begging of your php script.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

?>
```

This will show you error.

By seeing your code please do some changes.

1: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);` this code at begging of php script.

2: and remove `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query` from if condition.
so your code should be something like this.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    if($i == 0){
        echo "$row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3]";
    } 
    else{
        echo "*$row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3]";
    } 
    $i++;

} 
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

3: and (i guess) here `mysqli_connect("localhost","*****", "****", "****")` should be your sever IP address. like

`mysqli_connect("192.168.0.1","*****", "****", "****")`

Comment: This will show the error in my browser when I run or somewhere else?

Comment: wherever you execute your script it will shoe you error, if it is browser or client like postman, it doesn't matter.

Comment: But I added the line and made a little error in my script. It still doesn't show the error. Script : http://arqamahmad.com/music_app/getmusic.php